# FlowLayoutPanel designtime differs from runtime

Tags: vb.net, flowlayoutpanel

I'm trying to add RadioButtons to a FlowLayoutPanel and while at design time they are correctly disposed horizontally, the moment I run the program they get stacked vertically and a scrollbar appears.

The FlowLayoutPanel properties are all default but the fact that it's docked at the top of the form.

Comment: That's one of those problems you as a developer have to solve on your own.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem.

I had function that set all FlowLayoutPanels as TopDown, and this one was also set as TopDown at creation.